# How to evaluate my own text classifier

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, text-mining

I have written my own text classifier, based on some linguistic theory. Final outcome of the classifier is a tuple pair of an article title and the binary category.

I also used the NB classifier on my Golden standard corpus and evaluated its performance with CV, using Sci-kit learn library in Python. However, I am struggling to figure out how to evaluate performance of my own classifier. :S

I would really appreciate your ideas, since I am not experienced machine learner.

Thanks,

Guzdeh

Comment: Choose a reasonable metric from [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics) and prepare your data to be compatible. If you have chosen a good one within your NB-CV, then you can take it again

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate a classifier, the most common metric is accuracy, but there is no rule of thumb for all possible scenarios, so I would suggest that you read a bit about evaluation metric for classifiers. Also read about evaluation methodology.

If you are out of time, stick to accuracy and cross validation for now, but be sure to understand what a given metric means, what your methodology means, how to read a confusion matrix, each metric and methodology pros and cons, and specially its limitations.

Scikit Learn's Reference Page for its metrics: [Link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics)

Scikit Learn's User Guide for cross-validation: [Link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#)

You stated you have your golden standard. You said you have your model. You then only need to choose a metric and an evaluation methodology.

Your model will predict a class/target given an input (a set of features). The prediction will then be compared to your ground truth/golden standard.

Comment: thanks for your replies, I calculated the accuracy for my classifier for now. I am a bit in a hurry. However, I would also like to conduct a kNN classification using cosine similarity scores but do not know how to transform the cosine similarities into distances to be used with kNN. I cannot find anything useful on-line. Does anyone have any recommendations. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Cosine Similarity is a pairwise metric, so its not used directly in classification. You can use however a KNN classifier directly with your design matrix (vectorized text corpus), Scikit Learn provides one: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html

Comment: Just an additional comment. What is the reason for you to want to measure how similar your documents are? If you want to rank the documents by similarity, then this is a typical Information Retrieval problem (similar to a search engine). Let me know if you are willing to follow this direction, cause then you will not need a classifier.

Comment: I am building a lexicon, based on theoretically informed seed words, in order to classify articles based on how authors position themselves in texts. Theoretically there are three hierarchical levels with nine categories at the lowest level. I have lexicons for each of the categories but I am classifying the articles at the highest, binary level at the moment. So its binary classification issue.